# What does 俺のせいとも思われなかった mean here?

Tags: meaning

> 「そういえば……助けたといえば、あの時のは何だったの？急に突き飛ばされた気がしたんだけど」
>
> 「ああ……」
>
> さて、どう言ったものか。ここでまた妖精なんて言ったら、今度こそ終わりだろうし。
>
> 「近くにいたけど、俺にもよくわからなかったな。でも助かったんだし、いいんじゃないか？」
>
> 「それはさすがにすっきりしないんだけど……」
>
> 結局、誤魔化すしかなかったが、納得してはもらえなかった。**ただ、俺のせいとも思われなかったが**。

What exactly is he saying in the last sentence?

It looks like he is saying that he doesn't believe he is to blame, but I'm not quite sure what he means.

Comment: Hint: Who is the subject of 思う？ (It's passive.)

Answer (score 5):

The 思われなかった here is the [indirect passive (間接受身) / suffering passive (迷惑の受身)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%97%E5%8B%95%E6%85%8B#.E9.96.93.E6.8E.A5.E5.8F.97.E8.BA.AB). The subject of the passive 思われる is 俺, and the subject of 思う is the other person. 「俺は彼に『俺のせい（だ）』と思われる」 literally means "I am thought that it was my fault by him", which probably makes little sense in English. You say 「(私は) Someone + に + Sentence + と思われる」 to mean "(Someone) thinks ~~, which affects me (in some way)," and it's often translated as "I have (someone) think ~~." This kind of passive form doesn't have a corresponding active form: *彼は俺を/に、俺のせいだと思う.

> (俺は彼に)納得してはもらえなかった。ただ、(俺は彼に)「(彼が急に突き飛ばされたのは)俺のせい」とも思われなかったが。
>   I couldn't convince him. I didn't have him think that it was my fault either, though. / He wasn't happy with my explanation. He didn't think it was my fault either, though.

Answer (score 0):

思う: to think
思われる: to be thought
思われなかった: was not thought

俺のせいとも思われなかった
My fault was not thought either.
They didn't think it was my fault either.